# How to compare three or more molecular structures?

Tags: computational-chemistry, molecular-structure, cheminformatics

Let's say you have three or more different geometry files (xyz) for the same structure and you want to compare them. What would be best way for that?

Comment: [RMSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-mean-square_deviation_of_atomic_positions) seems like the first obvious choice. Although, of course, it depends on exactly *what* you are trying to compare them for...

Comment: Isn't it just for two geometry files?

Comment: Somebody else will probably have a better idea, but I guess what you're saying isn't entirely clear to me. If you want to sort a list of three or more items, it appears to me that you need some kind of pairwise comparison...

Comment: You mean I need a geometry file also for reference?

Comment: No, I think my point is just that comparison functions are written for two inputs. For example, you can't compare the numbers 3, 4, and 5 all at once. You can sort them by saying that 3 < 4 < 5, but implicitly you're using a pairwise comparison 3 < 4, 3 < 5, and 4 < 5. So what exactly are you trying to achieve with this? It might be helpful if you added some more context to your question.

Comment: I basically want to compare atom positions of these files with each other

Comment: Do you know the system will be orientated the same in each case

Answer (score 6):

**TL;DR** There is no generic best way. Develop a meaningful comparison for your system first, then the question of how to compare multiple structures will become less convoluted. Pick a reference structure to draw your conclusions.

### Compare only two structures

The whole issue depends on finding a meaningful way to compare structures in the first place. Naively one would assume that an [root-mean-square deviation of atomic positions (RMSD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-mean-square_deviation_of_atomic_positions)<sup>[1]</sup> is a good way to compare two structures, but for most practical purposes it won't. With this approach you'll condense two sets of information (quite a lot of information) into a single number. If you don't have a scale, then what does it mean.

A simple example, take the structures of butadiene:<sup>[2]</sup>

[image: Two structures of butadiene]

For this example, the calculated RMSD is `1.4513261239839574`.<sup>[0]</sup> In a strict sense, if you swap atoms 9 and 10, because a rotation happens, the RMSD should be different. A well implemented algorithm will know that these atoms are indistinguishable and produce the same RMSD. However, order matters sometimes, so be aware of that, too.

To the more elementary question: What does this number actually mean. So we would need some kind of scale. From a visual inspection, we would say they are quite different structures; from an (implied) chemical understanding we'LL immediately pick up that there is (in first approximation) a single dihedral different. In this case a more meaningful comparison would be structure parameters like bond distances, angles, dihedrals, or out-of-plane angles.

A counter example, now just considering *trans*-butadiene as structure, but comparing the methods RI-BP86/def2-SVP and RI-PBE/def2-SVP.<sup>[3]</sup> Now the RMSD is `0.0019595403851554454`. If the question is how well these methods agree with each other, then the temptative answer is *quite well*. But again, if it were not for experience, that value could mean anything.

A counter counter example, would be on how reliably one method of calculation will reproduce itself. Now using repeated calculations of *trans*-butadiene at the RI-PBE/def2-SVP level of theory, the RMSD is `2.0844418808250816e-16`. That is basically zero, isn't it. But without knowing what we have compared and what to expect, this value could again mean anything.

With everything considered this far, we only know how well (in an unknown fashion though) two structures compare. This is like comparing 2 and 3; thus finding out the RMSD is 1. That doesn't really help.
However, if you want to know how well PBE will reproduce the structure of BP86, then the RMSD suddenly becomes a lot more clear. While it doesn't really matter with a comparison of two sets, picking a reference case for your comparison matters to the question.

**In conclusion** calculating the RMSD for two structures might or might not be the way to go. What you'll always need is a reference, otherwise your question might be meaningless.

### Multiple structures

Now that we have established that comparing two structures depends heavily on the question that is being asked, we know that this will apply here, too.

For example, if you consider a conformational space, consider the low energy structure as reference. Then you can actually sort your structures according to the RMSD to that structure. Programs which determine conformational space will actually use such an approach.

If you want to know how well a computational method reproduces a crystal structure, you have pretty much already picked the reference. What you now need to figure out is whether the RMSD is helpful. Going from condensed phase to gas phase will lead to different problems. Angles and dihedrals are influenced by other molecules you might not be considering. However, if you just look at the bond lengths, you can also draw conclusion which method reproduces a parameter best.
In any case, you might want to consider omitting hydrogen atoms from the structure.
This is quite frequently done when benchmarking a methodology for investigations of the reaction mechanism. It is also a good way to use to *'calibrate Density Functional Approximations'* (DFA).

If you want to justify that your chosen method reproduces the structures well enough as an approximation, then the obvious choice would be the method you want to use. This has often be done to show that using a simple DFA using less time will produce reasonably well converged structures thus skipping expensive reoptimisations.

There certainly are more things to consider, but I think this illustrates the problem with the whole approach. If you want to compare three things, you need to know how to compare the first, then what to compare them against. If you cannot answer this question, your comparison might not be useful.

As always, look at the literature what others are doing for similar systems, then try to approach yours the same way.

#### Notes & References

0. I will be omitting the unit from all values; angstrom is therefore implies. This is simply because the programs used will also imply the units.
1. There is a nice implementation of RMSD in python available on GitHub: https://github.com/charnley/rmsd. It will be used here, too.
2. Optimised with xtb, see https://github.com/grimme-lab/xtb

   *trans*-butadiene:

   ```
   C        0.989655924      0.075383602     -0.024713443
   C        2.317729081      0.061870073      0.001720395
   C        3.092825332     -0.523680990      1.074346659
   C        4.420898600     -0.536792302      1.100972837
   H        0.437167570      0.519522240     -0.834969799
   H        0.405781945     -0.358847639      0.771074562
   H        2.884926249      0.505132896     -0.807127933
   H        2.525654828     -0.966802276      1.883291521
   H        5.004795037     -0.101504125      0.305779782
   H        4.973395433     -0.980161479      1.911645418
   ```

   *cis*-butadiene:

   ```
   C        0.960901519      0.102797367     -0.074150724
   C        2.285553694      0.054182217      0.015302774
   C        3.054624452     -0.537267624      1.098841827
   C        2.562107526     -1.129034473      2.181574196
   H        0.470193589      0.563081554     -0.914527335
   H        0.316113842     -0.309782226      0.682610316
   H        2.879283339      0.488966088     -0.779420603
   H        4.129461610     -0.473089986      0.981620967
   H        1.504218325     -1.224871958      2.355773288
   H        3.205852103     -1.543149959      2.938534295
   ```
3. Calculations are performed with [Orca 4.2.1](https://orcaforum.kofo.mpg.de/app.php/portal).

   RI-BP86/def2-SVP:

   ```
   C   0.95575989884130      0.08100590986283     -0.03334466433621
   C   2.30910835995513      0.06320383319263      0.00080877611734
   C   3.10145823671758     -0.52437495050823      1.07559644898752
   C   4.45480621149184     -0.54218133779601      1.10974928378639
   H   0.40481134955806      0.53782521459098     -0.86973010000421
   H   0.35678816482669     -0.36408211138767      0.77899770211471
   H   2.87466566256150      0.51941793049988     -0.83303737235663
   H   2.53590053819549     -0.98058344364338      1.90944605848559
   H   5.05377847073995     -0.09710562028587      0.29740171404077
   H   5.00575310711246     -0.99900542452517      1.94613215316474
   ```

   RI-PBE/def2-SVP:

   ```
   C   0.95730901184150      0.08075188309749     -0.03290025865850
   C   2.30976982144587      0.06285884282725      0.00142432803956
   C   3.10079629620100     -0.52403054214147      1.07498080335691
   C   4.45325694810625     -0.54192705246080      1.10930497169718
   H   0.40637317799734      0.53746037139229     -0.86906027083378
   H   0.35957667735107     -0.36458957651717      0.77995109642634
   H   2.87598438022296      0.51876441714347     -0.83182376939508
   H   2.53458184326634     -0.97993147006835      1.90823171834507
   H   5.05099013560010     -0.09659642313629      0.29644859687702
   H   5.00419170796757     -0.99864045013644      1.94546278414529
   ```

Comment: I think when I suggested RMSD I was thinking also about the possibility of clustering similar geometries together. It's not a comparison *per se*, but a fairly common thing to do, afaik. I refrained from posting an answer, because I really can't tell what OP wants to do...

Comment: @orthocresol I agree, it really isn't clear what OP wants or needs. RMSD also was my first impulse, just adding to use a reference structure. When it came down to answering, I realised the problems that come along with that approach. I hope I gave a basic overview about what can be done and what to consider before using such an approach.

Comment: I looked at this and decided anything beyond trying RMSD required a lot more depth, and even then wasn't sure I had a good answer - so didn't reply. I was thinking along the lines of the COM (after translation) comparison being like comparing dipole moments and Moments of Inertia like quadrupoles, so in some sense we are generating a multipole expansion of the mass od the structure, but using mass instead of charge. But while I can give recipes that generate number as @Martin-マーチン points out interpreting what those numbers mean is not straightforward.

Answer (score 3):

First I would calculate the centre of mass (com) then go on and calculate the moment of inertia axis vectors for each structure and use these to align them via a rotation matrix. Make the centre of mass the same for both first. Now start to measure the difference in position of each atom; find the mean or centre of the same atom's position between structures and make a sphere of the max radius of each group and plot these to see where your structures differ. You can then home in on parts that are most dissimilar.

A measure of the global difference may not mean much as some parts may be the same and some different.

Comment: If the C.O.M. are different it might just be a simple translation of the whole structure, which is otherwise identical

Comment: @Ian Bush ah yes, good point. I had assumed structure was about same xyz; finding the inertial axes should still work. I will edit the answer.